# Session timeout with multi-application session

Tags: timeout, oracle-apex

(APEX 4.1.1.00.23)

I have two applications A and B that share the same session (because they use the same session cookie), and each has Maximum Session Idle Time set to the same value N. Having established a session and visited both applications, if I then spend more than N seconds working in application A (doing lots of page loads so not timing out), if I then navigate to application B it immediately times out and sends me to its login page.

I tried also calling APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_MAX_IDLE_SECONDS(N) in both applications, with p_scopr defaulting to 'SESSION', noting that the API docs say

> This would be the most common use case when multiple Application
>   Express applications use a common authentication scheme and are
>   designed to operate as a suite in a common session.

However the same thing happens.

I want the timeout to apply to the session as a whole, not to each application independently. Is this not what the above is supposed to achieve, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to this from Christian Neumueller on [the Oracle APEX forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10793282):

> ... it's no issue anymore in 4.2. Looking at the 4.1.1
>   code, it seems that the problem is how we stored the last access time.
>   While the APEX_UTIL call with SESSION scope would set the idle timeout
>   for both apps, we maintained a timer (FSP_LAST_REQUEST_TIME) for each
>   app. Working in TIMTEST1 only updated the timer for TIMTEST1, not for
>   TIMTEST2. After working with one app and switching back to the other
>   app, Apex sees the stale timer and decides that the session expired.
>   This is clearly a bug. The bad news is that a backport is not
>   feasible, because so much has changed in session state management.